# Appcelerator. Open modal window in single context

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app with Appcelerator Titanium Studio and SDK 1.7.2.
I am working in a single context way of doing things (like tweetanium).
I know how to switch between windows but how can I open a modal window?

This kind of works but I cannot add a button to the navBar. It also
does not feel right at all.

```
 var wind = UI.Win({

  title: 'Twitter',
  modal: true

 });

 wind.open(Window.ShareTwitter());
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

you open a modal window the way you always do, nothing has changed...

```
window.open({modal:true});
```

Comment: But in my app windows are opened like this: tab['tab1'].open(Window.ContactsAdd()). How does Ti know which "file" to open if I don´t specify a function?

Comment: when you are opening a modal window, you do not specify a tab, you just open it

Comment: Yeah, but how can I specify what window/content that should fill the modal?